# How to input a word in ncurses screen?

Tags: python, ncurses

I was trying to use `raw_input()` function first, but find it in compatible with ncurses.
Then I tried `window.getch()` function, I can type and show characters on screen, but can't realize input. How can I input a word in `ncurses` and can use if statement to evaluate it?

For example, I wanna realize this in `ncurses`:

```
import ncurses
stdscr = curses.initscr()

# ???_input = "cool" # this is the missing input method I want to know
if ???_input == "cool":
    stdscr.addstr(1,1,"Super cool!")
stdscr.refresh()
stdscr.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Function `raw_input( )` doesn't works in curses mode, The `getch()` method returns an integer;  it represents the ASCII code of the key pressed. The will not work if you wants to scan string from prompt. You can make use of `getstr` function:

> #### [`window.getstr([y, x])`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getstr)
>
> Read a string from the user, with primitive line editing capacity.
>
> #### [User Input](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html#user-input)
>
> There’s also a method to retrieve an entire string, `getstr()`
>
> ```
> curses.echo()            # Enable echoing of characters
>
> # Get a 15-character string, with the cursor on the top line
> s = stdscr.getstr(0,0, 15)
> ```

And I wrote raw_input function as below:

```
def my_raw_input(stdscr, r, c, prompt_string):
    curses.echo() 
    stdscr.addstr(r, c, prompt_string)
    stdscr.refresh()
    input = stdscr.getstr(r + 1, c, 20)
    return input  #       ^^^^  reading input at next line
```

call it as `choice = my_raw_input(stdscr, 5, 5, "cool or hot?")`

**Edit:** Here is working example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    stdscr.clear()
    choice = my_raw_input(stdscr, 2, 3, "cool or hot?").lower()
    if choice == "cool":
        stdscr.addstr(5,3,"Super cool!")
    elif choice == "hot":
        stdscr.addstr(5, 3," HOT!") 
    else:
        stdscr.addstr(5, 3," Invalid input") 
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()
    curses.endwin()
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Two questions. In "input = stdscr.getstr(r + 1, c, 20)" Why should I read from r+1?(Beacuse the curosr automatically move to there?) What does the "20" mean after r+1 and c?

Comment: @Mario (1) I did `r + 1`  to move cursor to *next row*, (because courser will automatically move to next after `?`)

Comment: "20" means you can input 20 chars string. Read all comments and doc I add in answer