# Advanced input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to receive some information from a user in a next way:

My score is  of 10   - is already printed

Between 'is' and 'of' there is an empty place for user's input so he doesn't enter his information at the end( if using simple input() ) but in the middle. While user is entering some information it appears between 'is' and 'of'

Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

One way to get something close to what you want is if you terminal supports [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
x = input("My score is \x1b[s  of 10\x1b[u")
```

`\x1b` is the escape character. Neither escape character is dipsplayed on the screen; instead, they introduce byte sequences that the terminal interprets as an instruction of some kind. `ESC[s` tells the terminal to remember where the cursor is at the moment. `ESC[u` tells the terminal to move the cursor to the last-remembered position.

[image]

(The rectangle is the cursor in an unfocused window.)

Using a library that abstracts away the exact terminal you are using is preferable, but this gives you an idea of how such libraries interact with your terminal: it's all just bytes written to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

If you use console then consider importing curses library. It works on both linux and windows. Download it for windows from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses

With this library you have a total control over console. Here is the answer to your question. 
[How to input a word in ncurses screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784625/how-to-input-a-word-in-ncurses-screen)

Comment: The other way would be far more complicated; I accomplished it a few years ago, I dont remember the code, but I used carriage return ( \r ) and constantly refreshed the console.

Comment: So far this is the only answer that appears to have come from someone who took the trouble to read the question.

Comment: @Usmiech See my answer for one possible example.