# Can you use the python input function in a curses window - curses.newwin()? Curses - Python

Tags: python, python-curses

I am currently using `getch`, `getkey` and the `getstr` functions from the curses module and have found them **not user-friendly**. Why?

1. They are all slower to detect a keypress than the python `input()` function.
2. You have to hold the key down for longer than the usual press-down to make the program recognise it.

In my scenario though, I have a curses window, so I don't know how to, or if it's possible to use non-curses functions on it. I would like to know if there is a way of using the `input()` function on the curses window **or** just be able to position the input for the user to enter text.

If it's not possible, can you please provide an alternative. Thanks!

**Note: The user has to be able to see what they are typing as well.**

```
    view = curses.newwin(1,1,15,10)

    #Get user request even with curses window
    data = input()
```

Comment: As far as I know curses does not work in Windows

Comment: I think you misinterpreted "window". I meant `curses.newwin()` I'm using Linux to run the python script.

Comment: Are you sure [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21784625/2564301) is not all you need?

Comment: `getstr()` runs too slowly and is **not** `user-friendly` in my program